How to bulk update a database table from another table efficiently in a schema update?
I maintain the Visitors module. In an update yet to be released, I moved the performance metrics to a different table. The code below works, but it is not great.

Once during testing, the query timed out but the data was updated.
There is no way to update the progress bar.

Visitors is web analytics. Every page view is logged. Sites could have a vast number of records. The data is moving from a dedicated table for the performance metrics to the main visitors' table. The metrics used to be optional, but are now required. Moving them to the main table reduces database inserts. After the data is moved the visitors_performance table is dropped.
What is the better way to do this? I am hesitant about selecting the data in batches, and updating each row because of the time it would take to execute.
$database = \Drupal::database();
$database->query("UPDATE {visitors}
  INNER JOIN {visitors_performance}
    ON {visitors_performance}.visitors_id = {visitors}.visitors_id
  SET
    visitors.pf_network = visitors_performance.network,
    visitors.pf_server = visitors_performance.server,
    visitors.pf_transfer = visitors_performance.transfer,
    visitors.pf_dom_processing = visitors_performance.dom_processing,
    visitors.pf_dom_complete = visitors_performance.dom_complete,
    visitors.pf_on_load = visitors_performance.on_load,
    visitors.pf_total = visitors_performance.total

  WHERE {visitors}.pf_total IS NULL");



Can you give more context? It helps with being able to provide Drupal-specific responses. Is the table renamed? Or are only some rows being moved? What is your end goal?

I re-titled this Question assuming you mean "in a schema update". If I'm wrong, please fix it.

I don't think there's really a way to answer this that will be satisfying. If you want top speed, you let the DB engine do it, and accept that you won't get realtime feedback, and I guess also accept the timeout risks if your system lets that happen. If you want a shinier UX, and less chance of timeouts, you batch up the operations so you can provide the feedback after each, and take the performance hit. And obviously there's any amount of in-between combination of those approaches - e.g for 1,000,000 rows you break it into 10 batches of 100,000, if it's over 10,000,000, 100 batches, and so on
